# SQL combine one column with another table and add new column

Tags: mysql, join

Sorry for the unclear title. But i want to make column editor_article which has name of editor. Only article with same value among id_article and parent_id have name of editor_article and editor_article has '0' value if id_section = 29 and if parent_id != 0. Editor_article got from editor column join with t_kolom.id_editor.

```
tbl_name:t_article
id_section  id_article      parent_id   editor
29          441             0           2
33          1093            18          2
33          18              0           0
29          3144            0           8
30          3136            0           0
31          3130            0           0
31          3140            3130        22
31          3141            3130        335
30          3142            3136        546

tbl_name:t_kolom
id_editor   name
1           john
2           gerrard
3           lukas
8           anthony
22          jimmy
335         eric
546         tyas
```

And the expected output:

```
id_section  id_article      parent_id   editor      editor_article
29          441             0           2           0
33          1093            18          2           0
33          18              0           0           gerrard
29          3144            0           8           0
30          3136            0           0           tyas
31          3130            0           0           jimmy,eric
31          3140            3130        22          0
31          3141            3130        335         0
30          3142            3136        546         0
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, Please add input and output with proper example

Comment: Can you explain the logic/criteria behind your output ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid the logic almost same like my question yesterday. but the value show the name of editor.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid the name of editor_article get from join t_article.editor and t_kolom.id_editor.